# Recovering drive via boot to Win7 setup command prompt

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, command-line, data-recovery, pata

I am trying to recover data from two old IDE drives. Drive1 has been successful, but something is wrong with Drive2. It does not appear as a drive letter.

Due to limited legacy hardware, the only way i can see these drives is to boot using windows 7 setup and goto the command prompt. Without going further as to why, my question is how i can access the data in this command prompt.

I discovered DISKPART command and while a first time user, it looked like something that can fix my problem. Here are the results of my diskpart commands. At the bottom is a image of the commands taken with a camera.

---

The Drive2 is present because when using the diskpart command, I can see it.

- How can I copy the information using a robocopy script if the drive
  letter is not available?
- how can I assign a drive letter?
- Is there
  any repair command I need to execute?

When i execute DISKPART, the following is what i see.

```
DISKPART> LIST DISK

Disk###  Status  Size  Free
Disk 5   Online 37 GB  2048 KB
```

So then I select disk 5.

```
DISKPART> SELECT DISK 5
```

*"Disk 5 is now the selected disk"*

When I list partition

```
DISKPART> LIST PARTITION
Partition ### Type    Size
Partition 1   Primary 101 MB
Partition 2   Primary 37 GB
```

So I select partition 2

*"Partition 2 is now the selected partition."*

I then try to assign a drive letter

```
DISKPART> ASSIGN LETTER=G
```

*"There is no volume specified."

"Please select a volume and try again."*

When i list volume the drive is not present.

```
DISKPART> LIST VOLUME
```

---

Result of the above commands
[image]

Comment: Connect the drive and see if it's detected by the BIOS. If not, there's probably not much you can do save use a professional data recovery service (if the data is important enough for you to spend a lot).

Comment: it is listed in the bios

Comment: Then try a Linux LiveCD/USB.